# Firebase cloud function returns null in Flutter because it's still running

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

UPDATE: I'm getting this out my firebase console: Function execution took 2906 ms, finished with status code: 200
And 15 seconds later, I get: the console.log DOC DOES EXIST

I'm running this cloud firestore function. It 'works' but I got constantly this as a return: FLUTTER: NULL

But within the firebase console I get the console.log that says 'DOC DOES EXIST'.

What could be the solution to this? Language TYPESCRIPT

Thank you very much!

```
  export const pubVer = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

      console.log(data.message);

      const kRef = admin.firestore().collection('Keys').doc(data.message)
      kRef.get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log('No such document!');
            return {returnMessage: 'FALSE'}
          } else {
            console.log('DOC DOES EXIST');
            return {'returnMessage: 'TRUE'}
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting document', err);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callable functions must return a promise that resolves with the data to send to the client.  As shown, the function isn't returning anything at the top level.  Returning from the `then` callback isn't sufficient.  You will also need to return the promise returned by `then`:

```
export const pubVer = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    console.log(data.message);

    const kRef = admin.firestore().collection('Keys').doc(data.message)
    return kRef.get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log('No such document!');
            return {returnMessage: 'FALSE'}
          } else {
            console.log('DOC DOES EXIST');
            return {'returnMessage: 'TRUE'}
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting document', err);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using async/await that could help you debug

```
export const pubVer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const documentId = data.message;
    const kRef = admin.firestore().collection('Keys').doc(documentId);
    try {
        const doc = await kRef.get();
        if (!doc.exists)
            throw new Error('No such document!');
        return doc.data();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! When returning doc.data(), I'm trying to set a new document in firestore with the users ID and mailadress. But when I try to implement it: it says :  "Promises must be handled appropriately"

Comment: @KarelDebedts Can you share your complete function?