# Flutter - Return Null value while using Http Request in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, xmlhttprequest

Here is my issue, I have a callable Cloud Function I would like to use on my Flutter app.

You can find the code below.

However, each time I press the button corresponding to the function I always have a "null" value on my app coming from Cloud Functions even if my answer is printed into the console.

From what I understand, the function return a "null" value as the jsonResponse is not here yet.

I would like to find a way to return the jsonResponse only when the answer is there.

I tried async, await, and promises already, but maybe I used it the wrong way ?

Thank you

```
// code on JS

exports.writeMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2");
  function makeRequest(method, url) {
    appleMusicKey = 'XXXXXXX'
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.open(method, url);
      http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + appleMusicKey);
      http.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
          resolve(JSON.parse(http.response)['data'][0]['attributes']['url'].toString());
        } else {
          reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: http.statusText
          });
        }
      };
      http.onerror = function () {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      };
      http.send();
    });
  }

  async function doAjaxThings() {
    var isrcCode = 'QMBZ92168114';
    let result = await makeRequest("GET", `https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/fr/songs?filter[isrc]=${isrcCode}`);
    
    console.log(result);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(result);
      reject('error');
    });
  }

  doAjaxThings();

});

// code on Flutter for calling the function

  Future<void> writeMessage(
  ) async {
    HttpsCallable callable =
        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('writeMessage');
    final resp = await callable.call();
    print(resp.data);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using in Flutter to make this call? Did you try invoking this method from Postman, for example, to make sure you're getting the proper response?

Comment: Thank you for your help !

I just added above my Flutter code, but that's basically just a function I put inside an ElevatedButton and when I press it, it prints the data in the terminal.

Regarding Postman, no I haven't try as I don't know what it is...

Comment: Hi, Let me know if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661340/firebase-cloud-function-returns-null-in-flutter-because-its-still-running